# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key (Split column in multiple columns using python)

Tags: python, regex

The question has been asked a lot, however I'm still not close to the solution. I have a column which looks something like this

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I want to do is separate the country and language in different columns like

```
Country    Language 
Vietnam    Vietnamese_display 1
Indonesia  Tamil__1
India      Tamil_Video_5
```

I'm using the following code to get it done however there are a lot of factors that needs to be taken into account and I'm not sure how to do it

```
df[['Country', 'Language']] = df['Line Item'].str.split('_\s+', n=1, expand=True)
```

How can I skip the first "_" to get my desired results? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df[['Country', 'Language']] = df['Line Item'].str.extract(r'^_*([^_]+)_(.+)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zck8Nk/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `_*` - 0 or more underscores
- `([^_]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(.+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than line break chars.

Pandas test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Line Item': ['Vietnam_Vietnamese_display 1','Indonesia_Tamil__1','India_Tamil_Video_5']})
df[['Country', 'Language']] = df['Line Item'].str.extract(r'^_*([^_]+)_(.+)')
df
#                      Line Item    Country              Language
# 0  Vietnam_Vietnamese_display 1    Vietnam  Vietnamese_display 1
# 1            Indonesia_Tamil__1  Indonesia              Tamil__1
# 2           India_Tamil_Video_5      India         Tamil_Video_5
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution however there is a problem the 2nd and 3rd countries has '_' in the start, it's '_Indonesia_Tamil__1' and ''_India_Tamil_Video_5'', so it doesn't work the original dataset

Comment: @hyeri Use `.str.extract(r'^_*([^_]+)_(.+)')`